# How to create a thick coloured bar across the top/bottom edges of a page [XeTeX]?

Tags: xetex, cv

I would like to create a thick bar along the top/bottom edges of my resume, like [this](https://creativemarket.com/DemeDev/1441785-Word-Resume-Cover-Letter-Template/screenshots/#screenshot1) or [this](https://creativemarket.com/ThemeDevisers/794270-ResumeCV/screenshots/#screenshot1).

I tried the usual suspects (\hline and ilk), but they all obey the vertical margins (which makes sense, of course). So, how could I add these bars of variable thickness and colour, regardless of my margin settings? The template I'm using needs XeTeX.

Comment: I personnaly used the resume proposed [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/jan-kusters-modern-looking-cv/xtmmqtxpkvdh)

Comment: Thanks! Overleaf is pretty sweet, hadn't accessed it in a while :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E.g. with eso-pic:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic,xcolor}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
 \AtPageUpperLeft{%
 \textcolor{red}{\rule[-1cm]{\paperwidth}{1cm}}}}

\begin{document}

blblb 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's super clean and effective--thanks! Since the question asks about the bottom edge as well, I would add the \AtPageLowerLeft to the answer.

Comment: Actually, it didn't quite work (despite appearing like it did in the preview). When I look at the PDF output, the bar stops a few mm short of the right edge of the document (which is odd, since the length is \paperwidth). Is there a quick and easy way to set the length to longer than paperwidth? I tried {2\paperwidth} but still the same result. It's as if the "printer" reached the edge of its range.

Comment: Ok, nvm: it was a problem with the PDF viewer I was using. Opened in Adobe and another program, and it worked. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure you can use larger values. But there should should be no space. Did you use exactly my code? Is your system up-to-date?

Comment: Seems to be a problem with Cinnamon's (Mint 18.3) Document Viewer. Doesn't happen in Adobe (Wine) or GIMP. But yes, my system is up to date and I used the same code.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work for you ?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\hspace{-0.3\linewidth}\makebox[1.5\linewidth][c]{\tikz{\filldraw[red](0,0) rectangle (22cm,5mm);}}
\end{document}
```

EDIT:

I changed the `documentclass` to `letter` to obtain the right positioning using information in [here](https://fr.sharelatex.com/learn/Page_size_and_margins#!#Paper_size.2C_orientation_and_margins)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{letter}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\hspace{-1in}\hspace{-\hoffset}\hspace{-\oddsidemargin}\makebox[\paperwidth][l]{\tikz{\filldraw[red,anchor=center](0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,5mm);}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey, this looks great, though the bar still obeys the margin. I tried tweaking with the parameters but couldn't find anything to move it to the edge. I.e., define absolute position?

Comment: That code didn't work for me; however, using the link you provided, I was able to make it work with \voffset. However, the code in the answer below looks cleaner (and worked right away), so, that seems to be the way to go.

Comment: The example compiles with pdflatex ..., unfortunately I do not use xetex much. I do not know why the margins are not working properly with the article class.

Comment: Yeah, that could be it. Still, it's good to have more than one way to do it--thanks for your help!